# In XML view, rows are misaligned

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to work with a `Layout` using the xml view instead of graphical layout, but I often see that when I place the cursor at a specific row, it's the row before (now showing ducplicate of that row). This is making it very difficult for me to work with xml as I can't directly see where I'm editing before I place the cursor at the right row.

The problem goes away when I restart Eclipse but this is not really an option for me as I work with big projects on a non-SSD harddrive (takes forever to start).
Any help is really appreciated!

[image: Eclipse XML screen-grab]

When I show line numbers I can see that the editor displays code beneath the numbered lines, as if it's using some sort of cached image of the code or something. As shown in the image, `</RelativeLayout>` is beneath row 38, which shouldn't be possible, and it's not clickable. Though when I click on row 38, `</RelativeLayout>` will be shown there as well. The whole view is like this. Row 10 is actually 9 and so on.

Comment: can u pls show the snippet or share what are you doing??

Comment: I'd be happy to share a screenshot when the problem occurs again. But it doesn't matter what XML I'm working on. It can show up anywhere in any file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...Just save the file, close it and open the xml again you should be able to edit it normally.No need of restarting Eclipse.

Comment: It works and it's a far better solution than restarting Eclipse. But I personally feel this is just a workaround for something that shouldn't happen at the first place. Almost the same situation as Eclipse giving ridiculous errors that disappear with Project > Clean.

Comment: This trick doesn't work for me anymore. Suggestions are more than welcome as I also get this problem just a few seconds after restarting eclipse.

Comment: Did you save your file and close it?

Comment: Actually this is a _Aha question!_ You have an answer only when you have been there. This solution works for me and I don't have any other solution I know.